# No Trading in Jaque's Station?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Yesterday I arrived at Jaque's Station for the first time and noticed there was menu for Refuelling, Repairing and Trading?
What am I missing? Do I need a certain rank in order to see these options?

Comment: should that be "there was no menu"?

Comment: No, the menu was available, but it did not offer the (usual) options for refuel, repair and trade commodities. Only Home, contact and "Aufträge" (sorry, I don't know what it's called in english).

Comment: Read here for more details plus screenshot: https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=116506&highlight=jaques+commodities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just scanned the official forum and obviously also all other players are observing this - currently the station is lacking repair facility, outfitting and commodities market. Probably a bug but anyway not a question of player rank.

Comment: Are you sure it's meant to have those facilities? Many stations lack one or more those services. What does it indicate in the services data when you look at the station on the system map?

Comment: The facilities have been available before the latest jump of the station.

Comment: That information should probably be in your question.

Comment: You are right - I assumed everybody knew about Jaques Station, but that was stupid.

Answer (score 4):

Some stations do not have all of the facilities.  When you check the stations details in the System Map you will see Commodities listed if it has a trading center.

This is not a bug.

Comment: Yes, but Jaques Station definitely IS supposed to offer trades, especially some rares! It's been in the GalNet news and in the official dev news in the forum.

Comment: Read here for more details plus screenshot: https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=116506&highlight=jaques+commodities